# Prod logs in symfony 2 not using root dir

Tags: symfony, apache2

I'm developping a symfony2 website. I'm using apache2.2.
Everything works fine in dev environment.
But when i want to try it on the prod environment, it goes :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'The stream or
file "/var/www/domain/app/logs/prod.log" could not be opened:  
fopen(/var/www/domain/app/logs/prod.log) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No 
such file or directory' in /var/www/myapp/app/cache/prod/classes.php on line 4799
```

Why is it trying to write in /var/www/domain since my application is in /var/www/myapp ?
I tried to modify the config_prod.yml to no result.
Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you clear the cache for production environment? `app/console cache:clear -e prod`

Comment: I can't it gives me the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Boris Guéry it was a cache problem, you were right, but i couldn't use de command line to clear it. I had to use rm -rf in the shell.

Thanks